# zend Relative Links not working in IE - no images

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm having an issue with IE and Zend Framework.  This one is bizarre.

With ZF, IE's messing up all relative links, which includes linking to images.  Here's an example:

```
<a href="/photos/">My Photos</a>
```

Will display as "http:///photos/" in IE.  Likewise, an image such as:

```
<img src="/images/picture.jpg" />
```

Will look for an image at "http:///images/picture.jpg".

What you can see is that IE is messing links up and not including the website's domain name for relative links.  It should be:

```
"http://example.com/photos/"
"http://example.com/images/picture.jpg"
```

If I make the images absolute, they work fine.  Putting:

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/picture.jpg" />
```

and the image appears.  This isn't happening in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, or Opera.

I'm trying to see if this is some sort of new security feature in IE8, but I'm not seeing anything.  And it's only happening under Zend Framework.  I have some sites that are not using ZF and relative links are working fine in IE.

Comment: Can you post your rewrite rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a <BASE> tag in your template that might be confusing IE somehow?

Otherwise, it's probably an issue with the site sending a malformed 302/301 redirect due to htaccess configuration, or a bad redirect call within one of your controller classes. <a href="/example.jpg">example</a> is totally standard and should work.

Try loading "http://example.com/images/picture.jpg" in Firefox/Firebug with the Net panel on and "persistent" clicked, and see if any redirects happen. If there's a redirect with a Location header that doesn't have the full URL (including the http://example.com – otherwise it's non-standard) it could be messing up IE somehow.

Comment: thanks man. I removed the <base href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>" /> from layout.phtml
and added following line in application.ini
resources.frontController.baseUrl = ""